# AngularJS - Unknown provider: undefinedProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error intermittently:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: undefinedProvider <- 
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/unpr?p0=undefinedProvider%20%3C-%20

It can be repeated up to 10 times.

It seems to happen the first time the page is loaded into the browser. Usually, when I refresh the page, the messages do not appear.

It's not a new application. It has been working for some time, but I have made changes. The fact that the symptom appears intermittently is making it difficult to isolate the change that caused it.

What is puzzling me is the `undefinedProvider`. Any suggestions on how to find the provider name would be welcome!

I am using the unminified version of AngularJS 1.2.16.

I have done the usual things like using the array syntax.

I know this is not much to go on, but I thought I would check if anybody has experienced something similar before cutting the code down to a plunker.

One thing I added fairly recently was to pass some config data in via an ejs variable from the node server (as recommended by the Google talk on 'Massive Apps' from ng-conf). It was working fine, but I wonder if there is some timing issue. Here's a snippet:

```
.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
  var profile = angular.copy(window.activeProfile);
  $provide.constant('Config', profile.config);
  console.log("Config:", profile.config);
}])

.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$window', 'Config', function ($rootScope, $state, $window, Config) {
```

The config is logged as I expect.

Comment: Might be silly question because it's an existing app and the problem doesn't happen sometimes, but did you add any JS files that you forgot to include on your page?

Comment: "It seems to happen the first time the page is loaded into the browser. Usually, when I refresh the page, the messages do not appear." - this sounds like it might be an issue of loading the JS files in the wrong order / at the wrong time. Once they are cached by the browser, they are instantly available and the problem goes away. Can you share some code of your main page?

Comment: The js is all concatenated into a single file.

Comment: I have added a snippet of code that I am vaguely suspicious of.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in ngAnimate 1.2.16 and later(or incompatibility with AngularStrap?). On earlier versions my app works, later versions give me this:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: undefinedProvider <- 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/$injector/unpr?p0=undefinedProvider%20%3C-%20
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js:78:12
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js:3709:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js:3836:39)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js:3714:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js:3836:39)
    at lookup (http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-animate.js:409:36)
    at animationRunner (http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-animate.js:458:17)
    at performAnimation (http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-animate.js:862:22)
    at http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-animate.js:623:13
    at Scope.$digest (http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js:12308:36)
```

I am not using ngAnimate directly, only through AngularStrap and Toaster directives.

My solution is to revert to Angular and angular-animate version 1.2.15.

Comment: Thanks. removing ngAnimate worked for me as well. this errors comes randomly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of trouble shooting items [located here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

Did you define your module more than once? Make sure you don't `angular.module('name', []);` twice with a array as the second argument.

Interestingly, calling `$injector.get(key);` with undefined as your key will give you this same error, but the callstack will easily point you to that.